# Can a service worker detect history navigation?

Tags: service-worker

I have a service worker that displays a splash screen while the main content loads in the background.

Unfortunately, this makes the experience worse on history navigations (e.g., back button) because the splash screen loses the page state (e.g., scroll position).

Is there a way for the service worker to detect that a FetchEvent is for a history navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `Request` object that's exposed via the `FetchEvent` interface won't have anything that specifically identifies it as being due to a history navigation. The [`mode` attribute](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode), for instance, will end up being set to `'navigate'`, which is the same value you'd see for navigations due to something other than a back button.

There is an `isReload` property on the `FetchEvent`, but the [service worker specification](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#fetch-event-isreload) goes out of its way to call out that only refreshes, and not history navigations, should result in a `true` value:

> Pressing the refresh button should be considered a reload while
>   clicking a link and pressing the back button should not. The behavior
>   of the Ctrl+l enter is left to the implementations of the user agents.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in knowing if the request is history navigation or not, would be glad to know that now you should be able to detect this.

Here is the updated spec: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-history-navigation-flag

```
self.addEventListener('fetch',(event) => {
    if (event.request.isHistoryNavigation) {
        // Enter code related to history navgiation
    }
});
```